# Convert PCCERT_CONTEXT to openssl use - X509 struct or ASN1

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

how can i convert this microsoft PCCERT_CONTEXT structure containing certificate to valid struct X509 or ASN1 which can be used with open SSL. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the `pbCertEncoded` member of that structure.